# Как запретить пользователям (по выборке) доступ к папке Unix

Tags: ubuntu, unix, выборка

Скажем есть пользователи 1,2,3,vasya.
Есть папка test.
Как запретить пользователям которые начинаются на цифры доступ к папке test?

Comment: Дать доступ только группе, вклчтть в группу vasya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пойти несколькими путями:

1. Самый простой:

1.1. создаем группу для пользователей, логин которых НЕ начинается с цифры:

```
sudo groupadd without_digits
```

1.2. меням группу у директории на созданную нами:

```
sudo chgrp without_digits test
```

1.3. выставляем права на доступ в данную директорию только для владельца и нашей группы

```
sudo chmod 770 test
```

1.3. добавляем всех пользователей, у которых должен быть доступ в эту группу:

```
for user in $(cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d':' | egrep -v '^[1-9].*'); 
do sudo usermod -a -G without_digits $user;
done
```

2. Вариант посложнее, [ACL](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/access_control_list)
3. Самый сложный, использовать системы вроде [SElinux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux) или [AppArmor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor)